# How to tell textmate to open .scss.erb files as SASS?

Tags: textmate, ruby-on-rails-3.1, textmatebundles

With Rails 3.1 I have to append  my scss files with .erb to use images in my css. It's causing me a problem with textmate though.

How do you tell textmate to always open .scss.erb files as SASS?

Here's an illustration of my problem:
http://screenr.com/Jjps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the official SCSS Textmate bundle:

https://github.com/kuroir/SCSS.tmbundle

Comment: Available for both Textmate 1 and Textmate 2!

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to .erb the sass files to include images, you can use the `image-url` helper provided by the sass-rails gem. This way you can keep files as .css.scss and TextMate highlighting will work.

```
background: #fff image-url("search.png") no-repeat scroll left center;
```

More info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass

If you have to .erb the sass files then the syntax highlighting in TextMate will only be fixed by adding support for a new language for scss.erb files in a bundle. This would be similar to the *HTML (Rails)* language in the popular Ruby On Rails bundle by drnic.

https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle/tree/master/Syntaxes